# Is “Know how to cook leeks”an idiom? What does “Read “Hamlet” and know how to cook leeks” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, word-usage

There was the following sentence in New York Times’ article (February 28) titled “What you learn at 40s.”:

> "Victor Hugo supposedly called 40 “the old age of youth.” - - The
>   conventional wisdom is that you’re still reasonably young, but that
>   everything is declining: health, fertility, the certainty that you
>   will one day **read “Hamlet” and know how to cook leeks**. Among my peers
>   there’s a now-or-never mood: We still have time for a second act, but
>   we’d better get moving on it."
>   http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/01/opinion/sunday/what-you-learn-in-your-40s.html?hp&rref=opinion&_r=0

What does the line -“Read Hamlet and know how to cook leeks” mean? Is “Know how to cook leeks” an idiom, for instance, to mean to get 'the worldly knowledge'?

Readers English Japanese Dictionary at hand carries “eat the leek” and “not worth a leek” as idioms, but don’t include “know how to cook leeks.”

Comment: Yoichi dude - almost always, when you ask a question, the answer is: "You (Yoichi) are correct; the example you give is just stupid and badly written."  It's just that simple man.  Heh!  You need to accept the general fact that, today, almost all English is incredibly badly written **especially among professional writers**, because they always try *to reach for humorous, over-written, often slangy forms that 'wittily' extend something, but are actually just stupid*. It's meant to be two separate phrases.

Comment: "cooking leeks" is an example of something **an old person would do**.  it's that simple - surprising nobody pointed this out.  ie, young people play video games and get drunk; old people do "sophisticated" things like haute cuisine, reading, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there’s no connection intended between the literary and culinary achievements. I think you are misparsing this as

> the certainty that you will someday read Hamlet and [as a result] know how to cook leeks

when in fact it is supposed to be parsed as

> the certainty that you will someday read Hamlet and [that you will also someday] know how to cook leeks.

Comment: I took it ‘the imprerative + and’ form. If there is no connection between Hamlet and cooking leeks, it makes more sence, though it seems to me too late-development choice for women at 40s.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Well, I read Hamlet when I was 12, but I never cooked a leek until I was 59!

Comment: @YoichiOishi - I didn't start cooking leeks until my late 30s. In the US, I was constantly asked by the cashiers what they were. Then the same with fennel, until recently.  I was even asked once why I would *want to* cook with those!

Comment: I have never cooked leeks, but I did recently have raw fennel. Amazing!

Answer (score 8):

Once you click on the link and read the article it's pretty clear *why* the author chose to combine the reading of Hamlet with the knowledge of cooking leeks.

> Entering middle age in Paris — the world’s epicenter of existentialism
>   — isn’t terribly helpful. With their signature blend of subtlety and
>   pessimism, the French carve up midlife into the “crisis of the 40s,”
>   the “crisis of the 50s” and the “noonday demon” (described by one
>   French writer as “when a man in his 50s falls in love with the
>   babysitter”).
>
> Victor Hugo supposedly called 40 “the old age of youth.” In Paris,
>   it’s when waiters start calling you “Madame” without an ironic wink.
>   [...]

The American author is celebrating her 44th birthday in Paris, the capital of France. France is famous for its fashion, its art, and for its cuisine. One of the most famous dishes being the classic *Vichyssoise*, which is a fancy title for 'cold leek and potato soup'. A dish that the writer may have tasted in many a restaurant as a young woman but had never cooked for herself or her family. How does a seemingly tough and bland vegetable produce such a delicate and flavoursome soup? Is probably a question many young women have asked themselves when faced with the vegetable for the first time.

The author argues that the certainty that one day we will be confident enough  to cook this long stalk *and* read *Hamlet* for pleasure, rather than for school homework declines as we pass our mid-forties. Time is running out, but it's not too late.

EDIT Thanks to @LessPop_MoreFizz for the precision.

Comment: Brilliant! And I chuckled at the irony. @StoneyB wrote: "I read Hamlet when I was 12, but I never cooked a leek until I was 59!" As for me, I was cooking _vichyssoise_ at 16, but didn't see a Shakespeare play until I reached 50. Seems the author is right – what an odd world we live it.

Comment: I cooked *vichyssoise* in my twenties but I've never seen Hamlet performed, but I did go and see Macbeth, in London once, (fringe theatre) and it was a very memorable experience. I still have two years to go before viewing the play, Hamlet. It's never too late, as they say!

Comment: You had it until that last 'Graf. The author is arguing that "the certainty you will someday" do these things *declines* in your 40's.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz you're right, the author is saying the over 40s generation are running out of time to do these things. Well spotted, I'll make the necessary adjustments. However, the OP wanted to know if "read Hamlet and know how to cook leeks" were an idiom, or a typical phrase. It's not, but it might catch on.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I was tempted to cast “accept” to your answer for your hinting “French connection” with “how to cook leeks.” It's valuable input. I had no idea about the combination of vichyssoise and leek until you made a point. Sautéed leeks is one of the most popular dish among Japanese, Chinese and possibly Korean like fried or poached egg frequently served on daily meals. So I wondered why women at 40s “will” or should learn how to cook leeks, and what is the significance of cooking leeks that I do once a week.

Comment: @YoichiOishi the very first time I cooked leek, I wasn't very successful, there was still dirt and soil trapped in the inner leaves and I didn't discard the tough greener ones. A bit like artichokes, you have to be ruthless and strip them down. The leeks that I buy in the open fruit and veg market are quite large and *leafy*. I would have accepted StoneyB's answer myself. He answered your question, I provided a bit of cultural background :)

Comment: Food is crap in Paris these days - I recommend bologna.  :)  I cooked leeks when I was a kid. And anyone who thinks they're young at 30 is a nutcase .. life is short! As Churchill says, yourself from 15-25 and after that enjoy being old and watching the young people putter around.

Answer (score 7):

I think the author could have used any expression that would be interpreted as *“something I'll get around to one day...”* (for example, making a quilt, teaching yourself how to play the guitar, or mastering a flip turn in the swimming pool – any generic “unfinished business” activity). In the song *Time*, Pink Floyd expressed talked about half-written poems or outlines, singing:

> *Every year is getting shorter, never seem to find the time
>
>   **Plans that either come to naught or half a page of scribbled lines***

It doesn't appear to be an established idiom. I had never heard it before. When I Googled `"know how to cook leeks"`, I found all of 28 hits on the internet; Google books only returned six hits for `"how to cook leeks"`.

Comment: Now, suddenly, we're up to 21,500 results for `"know how to cook leeks"`! Once you actually go to page ten, though, the number drops to 33...

Comment: @WChargin. It looks like as though almost half of EL&U users rushed to Google to check up “know how to cook leeks” in vain.

Comment: @WChargin - Always take the hit count on Page 1 with a very large grain of salt :^) (Google reported tens of thousands of hits on my first page, too.)

Comment: Yep. On the other hand sometimes it underestimates them on the last page: doing a search for "PHP" yields 25 billion results, but jumping to the last page (page 39) takes that number down to 390. Obviously there's far more pages on PHP than that. Also interesting that they limit it to 39 pages anyway, so it doesn't matter if there's a trillion hits - you won't see them.

Answer (score 1):

This parses badly because the future tense is taken to be implied in the second half of the conjunction.  Changing "know" to "will know" would make clear that knowing how to cook happens at some time in the future, not necessarily at the time *Hamlet* is read:

> ... everything is declining: ... the certainty that you will one day read “Hamlet” and will know how to cook leeks

It still looks strange; certainty of one has nothing to do with certainty of the other.